# How to calculate a group probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem:

> If I have 10 monkeys and 30 bananas, and the monkeys are all
>   equally likely to eat each banana.  What is the probability that every
>   monkey eats at least 2 bananas?

Could someone walk me through this?

Comment: How can every monkey eat at least 2 bananas, if you have only 10 bananas.

Comment: @calculus I updated the question, I had worded it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are 30 bananas and 10 monkeys, there are
$$\binom{30+10-1}{30}$$
ways to distribute the bananas to the monkeys.

Now, to count the number of ways to distribute the bananas to the monkeys with each monkey getting at least 2 bananas, we first distribute 2 bananas each to the monkeys, leaving 10 bananas to distribute. Now, we need to distribute the 10 remaining bananas, for which there are
$$\binom{10+10-1}{10}$$
ways.

Hence, the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{10+10-1}{10}}{\binom{30+10-1}{30}}.$$

Comment: Thanks, the R code is 
``f1 <- function(n,k) {factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*(factorial(n-k)))}
f1(n=19, k=10)/f1(n=39, k=30)``

Answer (score 0):

This is the same to ask the ways to sum 30 with 10 numbers each one equal or bigger than 2. And this is the same amount that distribute 20 bananas on 10 monkeys, i.e., normalize the numbers to 1 as minimum subtracting 1 to each monkey.

The ways to sum a quantity S with N positive numbers (with repetition) is $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) for more details).

So the probability will be valid cases divided by the total possible cases

$$p=\frac{\binom{20-1}{10-1}}{\binom{30-1}{10-1}}=\frac{(19)_9}{(29)_9}=\frac{646}{70035}\approx 1\%$$

P.S.: I supposed at least one banana for each monkey. If you can let some monkey with zero bananas then the calculus is different.